# Typing code using a BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

Is a BlackBerry feasible for writing code with?

Additionally: Are there some programming languages which are specially easy or hard to type on it's keyboard?

I don't know BB well, but I'm trying to evaluate it for writing code while commuting. AFAIK, it doesn't have a "full-featured" keybard, and there are other phones with a more complete one. But I'd also like to be able to write text single-handedly, and I believe it's possible on a BB (?).

**Note:** that's not a question about writing code *for* a BlackBerry, but rather *on* one.

*(If that's not a good site for such a question, please let me know where could I pose it. I've let myself put it here based on the "matters that are unique to the programming profession" entry in the FAQ.)*

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider a netbook if you need something cheap you can write code with on-the-go. I've tried too, but mobile phones (no matter how smart they are) can't be used for writing code (unless you're willing to spend 1 hour to write a "Hello, World!" app).

Comment: And to answer your second question: the best language you could probably use is PHP, or even AutoIT, as these languages only need alphanumeric chars, brackets and quotes for basic functionality.

Comment: Have you tried specifically on a BlackBerry? What exactly were the biggest problems you ran into?  
PHP needs `{}` quite often, and that doesn't seem to be easily available on BB keyboard (I've tried looking through Google Images)?

Comment: On my friend's BlackBerry. The keys are too small.

Comment: A self-proclaimed [BlackBerry Touch Typist Guide](http://www.blackberryforums.com/general-blackberry-discussion/800-blackberry-thumb-touch-typist-guide-typing-60-wpm-without-looking.html) seems to claim that 50-60 WPM on a BB is quite possible.

Comment: How to type 50-60
WPM on BlackBerry
in 2 weeks!*
(*Assumes you are already a
desktop PC keyboard touch
typist)
It requires training.